# Angular app not responding to click in Selenium w/ PhantomJS

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium, phantomjs

In our app, we have two places were wie ha free text search field. Below is button to show an area for extended search options. This works in both places on Chrome with Selenium Java as testing tool but in just one place with PhantomJS. What does not work is showing the extended option by clicking the button.

The button looks like this:

```
<a id="extendSearch" href="javascript:;"[ngClass]="setToggleExtendedSearchLinkClasses()" (click)="toggleExtendedSearch()">
    {{extendSearch | translation}}
    <span class="JM_icon-check" [attr.data-check]="isFilterSelected() ? true : false"></span>
</a>
```

The function "toggleExtendedSearch()" looks like this:

```
toggleExtendedSearch() {
    console.log("document-search component: toggleExtendedSearch is called");
    if (this.extendedSearchOn) {
        this.extendedSearchOn = false;
    }
    else {
        this.extendedSearchOn = true;
    }
    console.log("document-search component.toggleExtendedSearch:" + this.extendedSearchOn);
}
```

The area for the extended search option is displayed with this Angular tag:

```
  <app-document-search-extended #extendedSearch [hidden]="!extendedSearchOn" (onFilterReset)="resetAllFilters($event)"
                            (onSubmitFilter)="toggleExtendedSearch()"></app-document-search-extended>
```

The code of the test case looks like this:

```
    SyncingWebDriverEventListener.whenStable(driver, extendSearch);
    extendSearch.click();
    SyncingWebDriverEventListener.whenStable(driver, extendSearch);

    Select dropdownFoerderbereiche = new Select(foerderbereiche);
    List<WebElement> optionsFoerderbereiche = dropdownFoerderbereiche.getOptions();

    LogEntries logs = driver.manage().logs().get("browser");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("==================== Start Browser Console Log ====================");
    System.out.println();
    for(LogEntry entry : logs) {
        System.out.println(entry.toString());
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("==================== End Browser Console Log ====================");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    dropdownFoerderbereiche.selectByIndex(1);
```

"extendedSearch" is the button in question and the "click89" works without error, at least according to Selenium, but it does not actually do what is hould do. "dropdownFoerderbereiche.selectByIndex(1);" then breaks, because "dropdownFoerderbereiche" is inside the area which the above click should show, but does not. So Selenium breaks because it refuses to manipulate an invisible element.

"SyncingWebDriverEventListener.whenStable(driver, extendSearch);" does in effect call "whenStable()" in the following JS-Code:

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    window.webtest = new function() {
        this.markers = {};

        this.whenStable = function(callback, element) {
            try {
                angular.getTestability(element || document.body).whenStable(callback);
            } catch (e) {
                callback();
            }
        };

        function _sendTimings(callback, angularRequestEnd) {
            try {
                var timing = {
                    url : location.href,
                    navigation : performance.timing,
                    angular : {
                        requestEnd : angularRequestEnd
                    },
                    resource : performance.getEntries ? performance.getEntries() : null
                };

                var json = JSON.stringify(timing);

                performance.clearResourceTimings && performance.clearResourceTimings();

                callback(json);
            } catch(e) {
                callback(null);
            }
        }

        this.loadMetrics = function(callback) {
            try {
                angular.getTestability(document.body).whenStable(function() {
                    _sendTimings(callback, performance.now());
                });
            } catch(e) {
                _sendTimings(callback);
            }
        };
    };

    console.log("Webtest js code active.");
})();
```

The error looks like this:

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: {"errorMessage":"Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated","request":{"headers":{"Accept-Encoding":"gzip,deflate","Connection":"Keep-Alive","Content-Length":"27","Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","Host":"localhost:48906","User-Agent":"Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/1.8.0_131)"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"id\":\":wdc:1497257910526\"}","url":"/click","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"click","directory":"/","path":"/click","relative":"/click","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/click","queryKey":{},"chunks":["click"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/44776180-4f4d-11e7-881c-c5c265e80666/element/:wdc:1497257910526/click"}}
Command duration or timeout: 157 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'
System info: host: 'VS2001', ip: '150.201.8.201', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=false, databaseEnabled=false, version=2.1.1, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, proxy={proxyType=direct}, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=false, driverVersion=1.2.0, locationContextEnabled=false, webStorageEnabled=false, browserName=phantomjs, takesScreenshot=true, driverName=ghostdriver, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 44776180-4f4d-11e7-881c-c5c265e80666

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:635)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:274)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$EventFiringWebElement$1.invoke(EventFiringWebDriver.java:331)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.click(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$EventFiringWebElement.click(EventFiringWebDriver.java:344)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select.setSelected(Select.java:324)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select.selectByIndex(Select.java:179)
    at de.lbank.hippo.selenium.pages.DocumentArchivePage.filterDocuments(DocumentArchivePage.java:137)
    at de.lbank.hippo.selenium.test.ShowDocumentArchiveTest.filterDocuments(ShowDocumentArchiveTest.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
    at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:48)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ScreenshotException: Screen shot has been taken
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'
System info: host: 'VS2001', ip: '150.201.8.201', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:142)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: {"errorMessage":"Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated","request":{"headers":{"Accept-Encoding":"gzip,deflate","Connection":"Keep-Alive","Content-Length":"27","Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","Host":"localhost:48906","User-Agent":"Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/1.8.0_131)"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"id\":\":wdc:1497257910526\"}","url":"/click","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"click","directory":"/","path":"/click","relative":"/click","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/click","queryKey":{},"chunks":["click"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/44776180-4f4d-11e7-881c-c5c265e80666/element/:wdc:1497257910526/click"}}
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'
System info: host: 'VS2001', ip: '150.201.8.201', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

We also tried simple waits for several to many seconds (i think from 5 to 10 or even 30 or 60) and also used ngWebDriver (https://github.com/paul-hammant/ngWebDriver) to wait but none of those did work. The other code location where it does work uses the following code to wait and it works there, but does not work on this location. It does use it only after the "click()".

```
public void waitUntilElementIsPresent(WebElement webElement) {
    ExpectedCondition clickableCondition = ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(webElement);
    this.waitForCondition(clickableCondition);
}
```

The code of the working part is the same.

In PhantomJS the function is called and "extendedSearchOn" is set to true (I logged it, as you can see). But nonetheless the area is still hidden. Since it works in the other place, there might be side effects, but I absolutely can't tell why. So maybe you can tell me what additional information you need to shed some light on it and I will gladly provide it.

We're using Selenium 3.0.1 and here's ng -v:

```
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.1
node: 6.9.4
os: win32 x64
@angular/common: 2.4.10
@angular/compiler: 2.4.10
@angular/core: 2.4.10
@angular/forms: 2.4.10
@angular/http: 2.4.10
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.10
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.10
@angular/router: 3.4.10
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.1
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.10
@angular/language-service: 4.1.3
```

Thanks,
Jan

Comment: You didn't post any of your test code. Try putting a breakpoint on the line that clicks the button and run it. Make sure the page is fully loaded before continuing and see if that fixes the issue. If it does, then you need a better wait there.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I added the test code, the actual error being logged and some more information on the code in general (everything between the Angular tag and "ng -v"). We tried many versions of waiting, but none did work for us. Two are in the description now.